# easydropdown, add option programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, easydropdown

I need to add some functionality to a page having two [easydropdowns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easydropdown?activeTab=readme#onselect), basically all my dropdowns are initialised by:

```
easydropdown.all({
    behavior: {
        liveUpdates: true,
        useNativeUiOnMobile: false
    }
});
```

I now need to edit one of them, so that when the user selects there a specific value, I add an extra option to the second easydropdown.

so far this is what I got:

```
    easydropdown('#first_dropdown select', {
    callbacks: {
        onSelect: value => {
            selector = $('#second_dropdown select')
            if(value == 'enable extra value on the second dropdown') {
                newOption = selector.find('option:last').clone();
                newOption.text('extra value');
                selector.append(newOption);
            } else {
                selector.find("option:contains(extra value)").remove();
            }
        }
    },
    behavior: {
        liveUpdates: true,
        useNativeUiOnMobile: false
    }
});

easydropdown.all({
    behavior: {
        liveUpdates: true,
        useNativeUiOnMobile: false
    }
});
```

now I have two issues with this:

- for the way my js is structured it's really ugly to pre activate easydropdown on that specific select, I would very much prefer not to edit the file containing `easydropdown.all` and add the callback in the file where I have js that is specific to this form. I couldn't find a way to.
- there must be a better way to add the extra option, this solution works, but it has a glitch, if I select the extra option, the first time I click on it the dropdown closes selecting the previous option, to get the extra option selected I need to open the dropdown again and select the extra option a second time.

any ideas?

thanks.

## update

- I found a more satisfying solution for the first issue, where I basically destroy and reconstruct the easydropdown for the dropdown I need to update.
- I still have troubles with the unselectable last result, here's a [fiddle about this](https://jsfiddle.net/3edxwpja/26/)

Comment: Can you convert your code to something runnable like Code snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: thanks, good idea I updated the question with the jsfiddle about it